# Javascript match multiple occurrences in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

So my current HTML looks like

```
<p class="comment-post-text">@333<br /> @44<br />@564</p>
```

I'm trying to create links that looks like

```
@333 @44 @564
```

However my result is

```
@333 @333 @333
```

and I'm using Regex to verify that if a number comes after the `@` symbol, transform the text into a link and link-back to the hash of the next post. It's a quoting system more or less. My problem is that it seems to only be matching the first occurrence of my regex, rather than matching for each occurrence.

```
$('.comment-post-text').each(function( index ) {
     let text = $( this ).text();
     let matches = text.match(/@(\d+)/);

       if(matches !== null){
        console.log(matches);
        let newText = replaceAll(text, /@(\d+)/, "<a href = '#pi_" + matches[1] + "'>" + matches[0] + "</a><br/>");
        $(this).replaceWith(newText);

       }
    });

  function replaceAll(str, find, replace) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

The problem is occurrence here at `matches[1]` it's only capturing the first occurrence of the pattern so looping through the matches array would be useless. Is there a way to have the matches array hold each occurrence of the match?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method to check if there is something to replace. Use the [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method directly with a backreference for the first capturing group `$1` and the whole match `$&` in the replacement string.

```
$('.comment-post-text').each(function( index ) {
    let text = $( this ).text();
    let newText = text.replace(/@(\d+)/g, "<a href = '#pi_$1'>$&</a><br/>");
    $(this).replaceWith(newText);
});
```

Comment: replace `replace` with `replaceAll` and it works perfect! Thank you.

Comment: @Tony: refresh the page and you will understand that the `replaceAll` method isn't usefull *(since it's only a flag in the pattern)*

Comment: replace doesn't work for me, I get `replace is not defined`